# Multiple having statements in a SQLAlchemy query

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

What is the order of operations in SQLAlechemy?  An ideal answer will provide a set of generally applicable rules rather than a solution in the context of a specific example.

The motivation for this question is as follows.  I am building a dataset from multiple tables within a SQLite3 database.  My query is something like the following:

```
query = session.query( Customer, Application, Income, Spending ).\
join(
    <USER-APPLICATION JOIN>
).\
join(
    <USER-INCOME JOIN>
).\
join(
    <USER-SPENDING JOIN>
).\
group_by(
    User.id,
    Application.date,
)
```

Now, I don't want to pull everything from these tables, so I put some filters on the query.  For example:

```
query = query.\
filter( 
    Income.date <= Application.date
).\
having(
    or_(
        and_(
            func.max(Spending.date) <= Application.date,
            Spending.date == func.max(Spending.date)
        ),
        and_(
            func.max(Spending.date) > Application.date,
            Spending.date < Application.date
        ),
        and_(
            func.min(Spending.date) > Application.date,
            Spending.date == func.min(Spending.date)
        )
    )
).\
having(
    Spending.date == func.max(Spending.date),
    Income.date == func.max(Income.date)
)
```

However, the having statements are dependent upon one-another, and the code above will do what I want if and only if the first having statement is applied before the second.

So is this code behaving in the way I want?  Also, does this behavior depend on which database I use (I may want to upgrade databases in the future)?

Comment: Set echo=False and see what SQLAlchemy is trying to do. Generally it produces reasonably performant query. Or you can write the query in raw SQL to get the optimum performance.

Comment: I edited my post so the second statement is a having statement.  For most filters the order would not matter.  But here I am using `func.max(Application.date)` inside <FILTER-2>, and that max depends on the first having statement.

Comment: Ahh! This is a much clearer question now that it's clarified not to be about runtime order of operations, but about query semantics.

Comment: It would be clearer, by the way, if you asked this as a question about SQL, not as a question about SQLAlchemy -- even if you just replaced the Python code with the SQL that each of those queries generated. You'd certainly get more responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of:

```
query.filter(...).having(...)
```

...anything in the `filter()` becomes part of a WHERE clause, and content in the `having()` becomes part of the HAVING clause.

The WHERE clause applies to rows pre-grouping, and the HAVING clause applies to groups. As such, the HAVING clause will implicitly be scoped to rows which passed the WHERE clause.

Thus, your code will behave appropriately as-written.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!  What if the second having depends of the first?  Please see edits above.